# Compositor nodes missing

Tags: interface, compositing-nodes

I have been doing some work on a file in the default view, doing all of my work there, including some compositing. However, after I decided to do the modeling in the default view, and make the compositing view used for compositing, I went to go adjust my compositor setup, but all my compositor nodes are gone, and I can't add any - all the options are grayed out. It appears the composition setup is still being applied to the render, but I can't find the setup. What happened? Where are my compositor nodes?

Comment: Make sure *Use nodes* is enabled in the header. If that's not it, could you upload your .blend?

Comment: That's not the problem. I've already had that checked from the beginning. Here it is: http://www.mediafire.com/download/wqdauob9jx8fcqf/CameraTrack.blend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a second scene called `testlight`, which has *Use nodes* disabled.

Enable nodes in `testlight`, then the nodes will appear and work fine in the main scene.

---

I'm not sure why this happens. I think it might be a bug, you might want to try reporting it (particularly if you can figure out how it got this way in the first place).

Re-disabling *use nodes* in `testlight` doesn't seem to disable nodes in the other scene again.

Comment: I added that scene when lighting was having issues. I never did compositing in there. Looks like switching it on and off got Blender to realize there were nodes again. Thanks!